# RedMi 2 Bootloop after MIUI update

Tags: boot-loop

Today I had I have received a MIUI updated on my RedMi 2.
[**Note:** The phone is rooted and has CWM installed]

The phone was supposed to boot and start the updated but for some reason it got stuck in bootloop.

At the moment I can only enter in fastboot mode, recovery it is not working.
How to recover it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here how I have managed to correctly boot the phone:

1. Boot in fastboot mode ( power + volume down )
2. Flash again CWM: `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
3. boot into CWM: `fastboot boot recovery.img`
4. reboot the system using CWM (fix root)
5. re-flash with flashify

step 3 is to be sure that CWM will be rebooted.
step 5 is to be sure CWM is flashed ( in the past I have experienced some problem flashing the recovery image with fastboot )

There is probably some other way but this way worked for me so it maybe useful to other as well.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to wipe cache partition.

Comment: add this as a comment / edit my answer or post a complete answer